# How to add to my Index/Show, so that it displays a table, from another table. (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

First post here, hope all is well with everyone! I am working on my senior project and struggling with this concept. Maybe it isn't possible, or it is and I'm thinking about it the wrong way.

I currently have this- This displays the student, with all its foreign keys in the other tables. In settings, there is a foreign key 'conversion_id.', I would like settings on the student call(code below) to ALSO display the conversion table, from the FK in settings.

```
$student = Student::with('studentIntroSurveys', 'settings', 'giftsSurveyResults', 
'studentGiftSurveys', 'devotionals', )->get();
```

If this does not make sense, I am sorry. I am still l new to the language.

(Code to display students. It shows settings, but not the conversions within settings.)

```
$student = Student::with('studentIntroSurveys', 'settings', 'giftsSurveyResults',
'studentGiftSurveys', 'devotionals', )->get();

if (!$student) {
    return response('No Data', 400);
} else {
    return response($student);
}
```

I would like it to display this settings, but WITH the conversion_id table!!
What it displays =

```
settings: { setting_id: 4, student_id: 1, dark_mode: 1, conversion_id: 1, 
notification_enabled: 1, notification_time: "08:00:00" } `
```

my has-one method =

```
public function settings()
{
    $settings = $this->hasOne(Settings::class, 'student_id', 'student_id');
    return $settings;
}
```

Comment: So `conversation` is a relationship on in the `Settings` model?

Comment: 'Conversion' is another table, and I want to display it in my 'Students Index'. But I am not sure how, because there is no foreign key relating the two.

Comment: So `conversation_id` isn't in the settings table?? Which relationship is it in?

Comment: @Rwd it is in the `settings` table, and `Student_id`, the primary key for `student`, is in the `Settings` table as well. I need to know how to get from the `student`, to the `settings` table, to the `conversions` table. Sorry my message was so confusing, thank you for asking questions!

Comment: Ok, that's fine :) So, do you have a `conversation` relationship set up in your `Setting` model?

Comment: I do, its the `Conversions` table primary key, `conversion_id`

I am just not sure what code I would use to call it in `student` index.

Comment: @Phantom I think you are asking for [`hasManyThrough`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through)

Comment: @matiaslauriti It wouldn't be a `hasOneThough` as the `conversation` relationship on the `Setting` model would be a `belongsTo` rather than `hasMany`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [dot syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading) for nested eager loading: `'settings.conversation'` e.g.

```
$student = Student::with('studentIntroSurveys', 'settings.conversation', 'giftsSurveyResults', 'studentGiftSurveys', 'devotionals', )->get();
```

Alternatively, you could set up a `belongsToMany` relationship on the `Student` model and use `settings` as the pivot table:

```
public function conversations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Conversation::class, 'settings')
}
```

---

Just a few FYIs:

Your `if` statement is never going to return the `400` response as `$student` is always going to be a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections). You could instead do `if ($student->isEmpty())`.

I would also recommend changing the variable to `$students` as it will be a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections) of students rather than a single student.

You can simple your `settings` relationship by removing the temporary variable and just returning the relationship:

```
public function settings()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Settings::class, 'student_id', 'student_id');
}
```

Comment: @Phantom super personal recommendation and tip, if you are new to Laravel/PHP, please, PLEASE, read the documentation as what you wanted was already explained there, I am just saying this so you don't waste time and get confused with answers here, the documentation is explaining everything, it is your friend.